# How to detect if a user has javascript enabled in nginx (or apache) conf file?

Tags: javascript, nginx, url-rewriting

is it possible to detect if a user has javascript enabled in nginx or apache config file then redirect them to a non-javascript webpage? I was thinking to use  tag in html, but my co-worker says that he can do it in conf file..., which I never heard of.

Answer (score 5):

No.